# Offline support for React Native App

Tags: ios, mobile, react-native

I am looking to add offline support to a React Native application. The app currently runs off an API that is backed by a Postgres db.

I am already using NetInfo to determine whether a user has a connection or not but am looking to understand the best way to add offline capabilities where a user can continue to update their data and information and then just have everything sync when they get a connection again.

It seems like a pouchdb/couchdb solution is often recommended - however, I don't want to change my database at all. Ideally, I'd love to have some sort of way to store "jobs" of API calls in a queue and then execute them once connection is restored.

What is the best way to go about getting this offline functionality on a React Native App.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what are you using to manage your application state?

Comment: Currently using Flux

Comment: if you are using Redux than you can use this library make your state available offline: https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist

Comment: @AakashSigdel Is this the only way to do it? Not much documentation at all on redux-persist

Comment: You could still use a lightweight client DB (PouchDB/CouchDB/etc) as your primary DB which your client will r/w to. You can then have a background-service synchronize it with the remote DB. This makes it easy to reason with your code. But it also depends on the nature of the app. I don't think there's a universal "best way". Could you write more about what your app does? How frequent is your sync? How would it handle conflicts.

Comment: @HazardouS thanks! The problem around handling conflicts and discrepancies is what I'm worried about if implementing a new DB. The sync would happen as soon as the user gets connectivity again; however, the app is also a web application as well (so the opportunity for the DBs to get out of sync is larger) and there are a lot of changes going on in my backend due to a number of chron jobs.

Comment: The pouchDB/CouchDB solution seems to work well for mobile only applications but we're already tied to Postgres as our main DB. The app essentially allows users to view and modify a calendar offline as well as change their data.

Comment: You can then take inspiration from CouchDB sync implementation. Basically, have a revision mechanism in your models. Whenever a client wants to write, have it present the current revision and only allow updates when it matches. Then when it doesn't you would need to write scenario specific conflict resolution logic. Even CouchDB sync doesn't claim to resolve everything automagically. It's not an easy road, but doable.

Comment: @Karim I have exactly this same problem. Did you end up finding a good way to go about implementing a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use e.g. redux for data storage in general. Assuming you have a `LOAD_POSTS_DATA` action, which a component may fire at a point of time you may use a  a reducer like this:

```
export const LOAD_POSTS_DATA = 'LOAD_POSTS_DATA';
var connected = ... // filled by NetInfo

const initialState = {
  data: [],
};

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOAD_POSTS_DATA:
      if (connected) {
        return {
          open: true,
        };  
      } 

      return state;

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export function load() {
  return {
    type: LOAD_POSTS_DATA,
  };
}
```

This would only not load the data, for the deferring you would write a second reducer like this:

```
const CLEAR_QUEUE = 'CLEAR_QUEUE';
import { LOAD_POSTS_DATA } from './otherReducer';
var connected = ... // filled by NetInfo

const initialState = {
  queue: [],
};

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOAD_POSTS_DATA:
      if (!connected) {
        var q = state.queue;
        q.push(action);

        return {
          queue: q,
        };  
      } 

      return state;

    case CLEAR_QUEUE:
      return {
        queue: []
      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

// needs to be called as soon as you go back only
// requires redux-thunk
export function getOperations() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { thisReducer: { queue } } = getState();
    queue.forEach(action => dispatch(action));

    return {
      type: CLEAR_QUEUE,
    };
  };
}
```

The second one stores every deferrable action (needs to be imported from other reducers) and uses [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) to get hold of the actions and dispatch them as soon as you are back online.

Comment: This will work smoothly I guess if not many requests in the queue to be executed. Also if dispatching actions results UI changes like notifications, animations etc then you would need to handle it outside this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at realm: https://realm.io, you can use it as database on your app, then as soon as you have the connectivity you can sync the data.